# *** Illegal NSTableView data source (<NSView: 0x102535290>). Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstableview

OK, this is driving me crazy, i have an Xcode OSX App that i have been working on. I made some changes recently and i have started getting the following error at compile time:

```
 iModerate Desktop[72478:303] *** Illegal NSTableView data source (<NSView: 0x102535290>).  
Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:
```

I cannot workout where this is coming from, i have implemented both these methods in my appDelegate:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
// The return value is typed as (id) because it will return a string in most cases.
id returnValue=nil;
// The column identifier string is the easiest way to identify a table column.
NSString *columnIdentifer = [tableColumn identifier];
// Get the name at the specified row in namesArray
NSString *theName = [[self.twitterClientsController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:row];
// Compare each column identifier and set the return value to
// the Person field value appropriate for the column.
if ([columnIdentifer isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
    returnValue = theName;
}
return returnValue;

}
```

and this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
return[[self.twitterClientsController arrangedObjects] count];
}
```

And app delegate is set as NSTableViewDelegate

Now the extra weird/frustrating thing, is that i have no NSTableView in the xib, i did, but i have deleted them all. I have event opened the XIB in BBedit and searched for NSTableView and there is 100% not one in there!

So, help please! If i could work out what NSView: 0x102535290 is i could maybe track this down.

Help to save my sanity greatly appreciated!

Gareth

Comment: Try to `NSLog(@"%p@,self);` somewhere in your delegate class, to print its address, and compare it to the address of the delegate reported in the error. They should match. Just to see if the delegate is properly set.

Comment: Is this still an issue? Make sure you dont have any other xibs which is creating this issue

Comment: In all honesty i really couldn't work this out, so i just reverted my changes via git and re-made the changes, and it was fine. Very very odd.

Answer (score 1):

it is solved with me that way :

- remove the datasource and the delegate connections from the interfaceBuilder.
- make an outlet property for the your tableview in the .h file
- in the .m file in applicationDidFinishLaunching method set the delegate and datasource manually for your tableview

  ```
  [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
  [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
  ```